# Create a category in different language?

Tags: multi-language, localization

Let's say my website in English, and I created a Spanish category which I want it to be Spanish language, it and it's child posts.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score -1):

This plugin did the job, for both posts and categories:
http://wordpress.org/plugins/polylang/